# Automatically redirecting old browsers to different "versions" of a website

Tags: php, css, internet-explorer-6, css-frameworks

This is going to sound crazy.

I want to support old browsers, like IE6 or Firefox 3. Just for the hell of it. There's already a framework to get me started, called min (http://mincss.com/docs.html). Great!

However, I'd like to (silently) redirect a user on a legacy browser to a directory containing the "optimized" page, containing the min css and html files. That way I know legacy users won't be served a modern page. Let me explain:

- when you load google.com, you can get many different versions of Google. Windows 2000 users, for example, get a Google homepage tailored "just for them".
- the redirect is silent, meaning no google.com/win2000 in the URL or something of the like. Kinda like how ErrorDocuments are silent.

Bonus points if I can manage to squeeze the min css into my original site and add conditionals so I truly only have one site.

Comment: Are you using PHP or java?

Comment: I actually haven't used PHP that much but I do plan to.

Comment: In that case use PHP to detect browser type and load the relevant page template. Google around for PHP template driven frameworks